# Unable to change HNSC HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: url, https, host-named, hnsc

I have a web application using host named site collections. I set it up using HTTP, later on I figured to use HTTP. I changed the AAM to use HTTPS as default and HTTP as Intranet Zone. Everything is working fine so far - I can access the sites using HTTPS as well as HTTP.

Unfortunately some standard web parts take the URL of the **default** Zone of the sites. Here comes the problem:

```
>> Get-SPSiteURL http://collaboration.domain.de

Url                                                                        Zone
---                                                                        ----
http://collaboration.domain.de/                                         Default
https://collaboration.domain.de/                                       Extranet
```

So the default is HTTP. I cannot change the default zone URL using [`Set-SPSiteUrl`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219633.aspx) and have to use [`SPSite.Rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.rename.aspx). No problem:

```
>> Remove-SPSiteUrl https://collaboration.domain.de
>> $site = get-spsite http://collaboration.domain.de
>> $site.Rename("https://collaboration.domain.de")
>> Set-SPSiteUrl -Identity https://collaboration.domain.de -Url http://collaboration.domain.de -Zone Intranet
```

Again, no errors. And checking the URLs again I get this:

```
>> Get-SPSiteUrl https://collaboration.domain.de

Url                                                                        Zone
---                                                                        ----
http://collaboration.domain.de/                                           Intranet
https://collaboration.domain.de/                                          Default
```

**Perfect!** (mind the order it's the other way around?) But here comes the problem. I cannot access the site anymore using HTTPS, I get access denied errors as well as these `System.ArgumentException` with `encodedValue`in the ULS log, see the relevant excerpt of the log here: http://pastebin.com/8QrtakKz. I'm using Windows Authentication (NTLM), not forms.

I can change the URL back with no problem using the same process as described above and everything starts working again, only with the wrong URL in the default zone.

---

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I change a HNSC (host named site collection) default zone URL from HTTP to HTTPS?
3. How can I change all site collections beneath the HNSC including a managed path (in this case it is /community/communitysite1, /community/communitysite2, ...) to have a default zone URL with HTTPS?

If all else fails, how can I backup the sites and restore them at a new location, but again with HNSC? I would like to use the suggested way of using `.Rename()`.

Disclaimer: I also posted to [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4a91acfd-9d93-494c-bc79-144fa0180e6d/spsiterename-not-working-from-http-to-https-hnsc) and will update with a solution if its found there.

Comment: In the AAM settings you have HTTPS for default Zone?

Comment: Yes, I extended the HSNC web application to HTTPS and changed the AAM mappings to the HTTPS URL is default, HTTP is Intranet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is **not possible** to switch to HTTPS after setting up the root HNSC web application without SSL (`-SecureSocketsLayer` parameter) - see ["SPSite.Rename not working from HTTP to HTTPS (HNSC)"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4a91acfd-9d93-494c-bc79-144fa0180e6d/spsiterename-not-working-from-http-to-https-hnsc).

**The solution:** You will have to delete the existing HSNC web application (make sure to not delete the content databases[!!!]) and recreate it with the `-SecureSocketsLayer` parameter in PowerShell. Afterwards you can change all the contained site collections with `Move-SPSite` and move them to the new `https` based location. Maybe you will also want to add HTTP back to the sites for which you can use `Set-SPSiteURL`.